# Find a primitive function for the antiderivative?

Tags: r

I've been searching on R help for a primitive function, because in my case I can't do it with `integrate` function, is there any way to find a primitive function (antiderivative)?

Comment: Why can't you do it with `integrate`?

Answer (score 3):

If it is a one-off, you can use a computer-algebra system ([Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), Maple, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), etc.).

If you want to do it from R, you can use the `Ryacas` package. 
For instance, `yacas(expression(integrate(sin)))` returns `-Cos(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no analytical method to generate F where F'=f and f is known but you can always approximate a value for a specific bounds when the bounds is known using the trapezoid approximation for instance.